# How to set id or name in select option tag using CodeIgniter form helper

Tags: php, codeigniter, drop-down-menu

How to create this html tag using form helper on codeigniter,.?

```
<select id='list_city' name='city'>
   <option id='city' value='0'>Bandung</option>
   <option id='city' value='1'>Cimahi</option>       
</select>
```

The concern of this question is how to set id='city' in option using CI Form_Helper. I need to set the id, because I'll use it in javascript later.

Comment: However you set it, though, it would be wrong if you give two equal IDs. IDs are supposed to be unique, you might likely encounter problems in your javascript if you do otherwise

Comment: Not sure that's possible.  May be better off just outputting it without the helper.  Looking at the function in the CI code doesn't look to have the ability to pass extra attributes to the `option` tag

Comment: If you use a JS framework that allows you to easily select elements with CSS selectors (jQuery for instance), there would be very little need to actually have an `id` or, more fittingly a `class` on the `option` elements. You'd simply use `select#list_city > option`, this will allow you to select the elements I assume you'd like to select with `option#city`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form_dropdown('country', $countryList, set_value('country', 'id="country" style="height: 30px;"'); ?>`

here countryList is an array where as key you put the option value and the value of each key is shown up on select option

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You would need to extend CI's Form Helper and modify `form_dropdown` to accept other attributes like ID's, etc. for each `<option>` The documentation has a section on [extending helpers](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html).

Answer (score 0):

You pass a string as the 4th argument:

```
$js = 'id="list_city"';
echo form_dropdown('city', $options, '', $js);
```

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Comment: That would pass the ID to the <select> tag, not to the individual options as asked by OP

Comment: Yes, you're right. I guess I didn't read the question thoroughly enough.